# CSS Issues for Mac vs Windows

Tags: html, css, windows, macos

I have been working on a form for a search bar and I have bumped into a problem. On my Windows PC I see that the search bar is how I coded it to be, but when I look on the Mac it's different in width.

(Both using Google Chrome)

Windows (How I want it to be)

[image]

Mac (I wish it was the same as Windows)

[image]

HTML:

```
<div id="searchBox">
<div id="searchBarHold">
<input type="text" class="searchBar" size="40" /><input type="button" value="SEARCH" class="searchButton" />
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#searchBox {width:368px;height:45px;background:url(../images/gradient.png) #333;border-radius:5px;float:left;}

#searchBarHold {padding:7px;}

.searchBar {padding:5px;width:border-radius:3px;border:none;}

.searchButton {height:27px;border-left:1px #f98923 solid;border-right:1px #f98923 solid;border-bottom:1px #f9b233 solid;border-top:1px #ffd797 solid;background:#f9b233;color:#fff;border-radius:3px;font-weight:900;}
```

Comment: Please add meaningful code here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: Ok thanks, and sorry i'm new to this.

Comment: You should test in different browsers too. I see no margin on any of those elements though (firefox/firebug). Which is what you would probably want. (margin-left: 5px; on the button fixes it for firefox). Also, look at setting the width in pixels with css (width: 200px; or whatever), not in character size.

Comment: Have you tried `box-sizing: border-box;` .. could be a potential fix. try & apply it to all 4 of the CSS selectors you've written

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using fixed widths. Couple things you could do here.

1) Make your text input and button input fixed widths so they take up the necessary space of your searchBox (remember to account for padding/margins)

2) Remove the width from your searchBox so it is only as wide as the children within it.

Answer (score 0):

I have given the widths to those inputs as different browsers are applying their own css which you are not overriding. so defining those widths, you will have more control on the appearance of elements. so, try [this](http://cdpn.io/grqtB), i have just tested on browser stack as well on ie9 and it works fine and play with the padding that you wanna give.

Comment: Its working fine on Mac how I have shown it on Windows? Also I tried adding a width to searchBarHold it just messed up even more by pushing the Search under the bar, even if it was 'width:10px;'.

Comment: @Rahul try [this](http://cdpn.io/grqtB) i have just tested on browser stack as well on ie9 and it works fine

Comment: @Rahul I have given the widths to those inputs as different browsers are applying their own css which you are not overriding. so defining those widths, you will have more control on the appearance of elements.